Formatting with Sed and write to other file giving empty records
I’m having an input file with one million records and formatting and writing to another file to a different location but some times it is writing empty file(intermittent).
Following is the scenario:
Input.out
Adding Header: echo "HSample" >> output.out
Details: cat Input.out | sed -e 's/^/D/' >> output.out
Trailer: echo "TSample" >> output.out
In the output.out it is writing only Trailer record without header and details.
This is happening intermittently, if I rerun it is ok.

Can you please reformat your question, and use code tags and proper formatting for the actual invocation? I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what you're actually doing.

"Sometimes" – Does this mean the task is recurring? You are using >>, so output.out should only grow, unless another process interferes. If there's only the trailer in output.out, something must have truncated or deleted the file. Is output.out an intermediate "node" in your workflow, providing data for the next step that eventually truncates the file?

Every day we run this job, weekly ones we notice this behaviour I.e. output generated with only trailer. This output is the final output file. No other program using this one.

So… every day you append to output.out by using … >> output.out and allegedly no other program uses the file, and still sometimes the file loses the data written so far. I think something else does truncate the file or the filesystem is corrupt or there is a bug in the shell that causes >> to truncate the file. For now the first possibility seems the most probable. Each of the three separate lines of code you posted should work as you expect.

Please do not cross-post. For the record, another copy is on Unix & Linux SE.

and on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79154132/formatting-with-sed-giving-an-empty-file

$ cd
$ cat check
echo "HSample" >> output.out
sed <.bashrc -e 's/^/D/' >> output.out
echo "TSample" >> output.out
$ . ./check
$ less ./check

Produces a copy of my .bashrc file, with H and T lines before and after, and file's lines prepended with D.
So... where is your problem?

What you posted should work. However, you may want to try the following. Here I assume file descriptor 5 in not already in use.
exec 5>>output.txt
echo "HSample" >&5
cat Input.out | sed -e 's/^/D/' >&5
echo "TSample" >&5
exec 5>&-

Note: I do not think the cat command is needed. I believe you could   simplify by reading directly from Input.out file, as shown below..
exec 5>>output.txt
echo "HSample" >&5
sed -e 's/^/D/' Input.out >&5
echo "TSample" >&5
exec 5>&-


Or use the file as a command line argument: sed -e 's/^/D/' Input.out

@Bodo: I guess I missed the obvious. I updated my answer.

I don't want to say that using a command line argument is always better than input redirection. It is just another option.
